# Ionic/Cordova : Change Return Key Label on Android & iOS

Tags: cordova, keyboard, return, label, ionic-framework

I am looking for a way to replace the "Done" (Android) or "return" (iOS) label of Softkeyboard by a more accurate one.

I have seen ways to do that natively, by editing properties of each input, but is there a way to just change it for the whole application regardless of the input, via native code of course ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using the new WKWebView on iOS, wrapping your `<input>` tags in a `<form>` tag will change the "return" key to a blue "go" key.

I am not aware of an effect on Android.